# Compiling c code in VsCode doesn't give an accurate result. It should return 4824, but does -1 instead

Tags: c

```
#include <math.h>


long long findNb(long long m)
{

    long long count = 0;
    long long volume = 0;
    
    while (volume < m)
    {   
        count++;
        volume += pow(count, 3);
    }
    
    if (volume == m)
    {
        return count;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
    

}


int main(void){
int x = findNb(135440716410000);

printf("%ld", x);


}
```

Comment: Do not use the floating point function `pow` for integer calculations. `pow(count, 3)` can be replaced by integer multiplication `count*count*count`.

Comment: Although @EugeneSh.'s suggestion is correct, there shouldn't have been any problem here. On most systems, a `double` variable can hold a 53-bit integer, which should be sufficient for calculating `pow(208063,3);` accurately. What happens when you run this: `int main() { long long i=0,i3=0; for(;i3==i*i*i;i3=pow(++i,3)){}; printf("Failed at i=%lld\n",i); return 0; }`

Comment: @r3mainer I think you ant `i3==pow(++i,3)`, `==`, not `=`.  Further, `i3==(long long)pow(++i,3)` is better to avoid `long long` to `double` conversion.

Comment: Note on the question title: although it's possible to configure [Visual Studio Code for a Microsoft C++ compiler](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc), I've used it with `gcc` on Linux. So it's useful to indicate the actual C compiler being used, since VS Code does not ship one.

Comment: @chux I know it's better to avoid `long long` to `double` conversion. I'm just curious to know when the first error occurs. I wasn't aiming to provide model code. The assignment (=) was intentional.

Comment: @Nagev I used **bold** `gcc` on Windows 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

**Weak `pow()`**

A weak `pow()` might not provide the best *integer* answer but a value just a tad less than expected.  This difference forms an off-by-one due to integer truncation with conversion of `pow()` result to `long long`.  For integer problems, best to use integer code, not *floating point*.

```
// volume += pow(count, 3);
volume += count * count * count;
```

**Potential lack of precision**

`pow(count, 3);` performs a `double` calculation with typically 53 bits of precision, yet OP's code better with 64-bit integer math. [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73802023/compiling-c-code-in-vscode-doesnt-give-an-accurate-result-it-should-return-482/73802246#comment130317349_73802023)
.

**Use consistent types and specifier**

```
long long x = findNb(135440716410000);
printf("%lld\n", x);
```

**Save time, enable all compiler warnings**

```
volume += pow(count, 3);
// warning: conversion from 'double' to 'long long int' may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]
```

Comment: Particularly, by using `long long` the OP needs 64 bits of precision, so for large values `pow` can give a result that's incorrect.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout In general that  is true.  With OP's 48-bit 135440716410000, I suspect a weak `pow()` is the real reason and not a certain precision limitation.

Comment: Could very well be. There are no accuracy guarantees on the math lib in the standard, right?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout True, The C lib does not specify that `pow(some_integer, 3)` must return some integer value.  In OPs. case, I suspect a value like `xxx.9999999999...` was retuned at one point instead of xxx+1.

Comment: Don't you need `LL` on the literal?

Comment: @thebusybee The `LL` is not needed. C identifies `135440716410000` as a _constant_, not a _literal_.